# In app purchases, multiple items?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, checkout

I've currently had in app purchases integrated for a while now, however it seems as though its only really setup for a small number of items to be sold, each item needs to be added to the catalog in the app, the app published then the in app product added in the developer dashboard,

What i need:

To be able to add 10+ products on a weekly basis available for download once purchased, is the ONLY way to do this updating the app weekly with all the new items added to the catalog?

P.s. I cannot do a  subscription model.

thank you!

Comment: I've never used in app purchase, isn't it possible to put the catalog online? would it be unsafe?

Comment: By catalog i mean :  new CatalogEntry("android.test.purchased",
                    R.string.android_test_purchased, Managed.UNMANAGED),

So im not exactly sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bulk import items in the developer console using CSV files. There is not API to get the items from the app though, so you need to put the list in an easily parsable format (XML, JSON, CSV, etc) on your server and have the app check and update its storefront if new items are available.

Comment: Okay, im parsing via XML into a listview now, however how can i make for instance a for while loop for the arrayList that will add a catalog entry for each item?

Comment: That's part of your own app and has little to do with in-app billing. Create an adapter as appropriate and use your `ArrayList`, etc. to back it.